# Turn 'Map Redraw' off in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Sometimes the print layout takes a long time to redraw if there's complex symbology and labelling in the data being shown. When editing the non map elements like the legend, scale bar, text disclaimers, position etc there is no need to see the map.

[image]

**Can the redraw be turned off or put into draft mode like in ArcMap?**
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/pausing-the-map-s-drawing.htm

Ideally another button in the map item properties
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivate the `Render` checkbox at the bottom right of the QGIS main window:
[image]

You can also try `Menu Settings / Options / Rendering` and increase `Map update interval` (250 ms by default).

[image]

Try deactivating the checkbox `Live update` at the bottom of the layer panel as well.

[image]